# Convexity of LASSO

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, regression

I would like to know if some variables in design matrix are correlated then LASSO is convex or not. If you give me a proof for convexity of LASSO and ADAPTIVE lasso, I will be thankful.
LASSO is defined by minimizing penalized likelihood function. Then in the context of regression with Gaussian errors we have
$$
L_n=||Y-X'\beta||_2^2 +\lambda_n||B||_1 ,\quad \lambda_n \geq 0
$$
So my question is, if some columns of $X$ are correlated, then how can I prove that $L_n$ is convex(if it is convex). It is obvious that my goal is minimizing $L_n$ with respect to $\beta$.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $XX'$ is positive semi-definite, then $L_n$ is convex.

Expand $\left \|Y-X'\beta \right \|_2^2$, we get $F(\beta)=Y'Y-2Y'X'\beta+\beta'XX'\beta$. $F(\beta)$ is convex with respect to $\beta$ when $XX'$ is positive semi-definite. As you know $\| \beta \|_1$ is convex, therefore $L_n$ is the sum of two convex function, it's convex.

Comment: Thanks, Could you please give me a proof?

Comment: Thank you. So as I understand, positive-semi-define means $det(XX')\geq 0$ then it means even if there exists correlation between variables in $X$ (as a result $det(XX')=0$), LASSO stays convex. Is that true?

Comment: @HAMEDHASELI positive-semi-define means all its eigenvalues should be larger or equal to 0.

Comment: Thanks you. So based based on your definition of positive-semi-defined matrix, LASSO is always convex either there exist correlation among variables or not. Could you please confirm this?

Comment: I found this in wikipedia : For any matrix A, the matrix A*A is positive semidefinite, and rank(A) = rank(A*A). The question arise in my mind is, if a function is convex, it means there exists a unique minimum. Then, why in high-dimensional cases (I mean when the number of variables is more than the number of observations) there are infinite possibilities for the solution of (LASSO)convex function?

Comment: @HAMEDHASELI for your first question. Mathematically, yes. For your second question, the minimum of the objective function is unique. But the the solution $\beta$ may not be unique unless $XX'$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I got that. For the last question, if you give me a reference for the first question (a tutorial or simple books), I would appreciate you much.

Comment: Dear @E.J., could you please confirm that semi positive definition of $(X'X)$ is sufficient for LASSO to be convex? (and could you please give me a reference for that)

Comment: any convex programming book helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have Convex optimization by Stephen Boyd. Maybe I am confused. If a function is convex, has it a unique minimum? (but maybe the way this minimum obtains is not unique). Is that true?

Comment: Dear @E.J., could you please take a look at my question in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168468/compact-and-convex-set